# Calling API in Angular service with variables

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api

I'm currently trying to access the access the Google Books API, which I have successfully managed to do directly in my controller, but for the sake of best practices I am wanting to move the business logic into a directive.

**HTML**

```
<form ng-submit="search(data)">
<div class="list">
  <div class="list list-inset">
    <label class="item item-input">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Search by Book Title" ng-model="data.isbn">
    </label>
  </div>
  <button class="button button-block button-positive" type="submit">
    Find Book
  </button>
</div>
```

Above I'm attaching **data.isbn** to the **search()** function.

**Controller.js**

```
.controller('DashCtrl', function($scope, BookSearch) {
  $scope.search = function(data) {
    $scope.books = BookSearch(data).all();
  };
})
```

I am then feeding that parameter to my **BookSearch** service.

**Service.js**

```
.factory('BookSearch', function ($http) {

  return function(data) {
    var api = "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=" + data;
    // Simple GET request example :
    $http.get(api).
      success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        var books = data;
      }).
      error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log(status);
      });

  }

  return {
    all: function() {
      return books;
    }
  }  


});
```

In the services.js I am wanting to access the Books API from Google with the search parameter and then write several functions, one of them being **all()** to simply return the books to **$scope.books** in the controller.

- I'm receiving this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'all' of undefined

When I try to make an http call inside the all() function, then $http.get does not even execute, as I am unable to log neither success nor error case and $scope.books remains undefined.

I am trying to stick with best practices in building a neat and scalable app and learning angular the way it should be.

I've looked at so many tutorials but they only ever use $http.get calls to static JSON files without parameters from the user.

Could anyone please advise whether I am going about this the right way and where my error is?

Comment: Do you have two return statements in your service or is that a typo?

Comment: Not a typo. I'm battling to understand how I can run the http.get request, with parameters, before I write functions that will affect the output. Surely I should not do the get requests inside the all() function?!

Comment: @user2341963 - That appears to be a jQuery related question.

Comment: indeed. sorry, my bad

Answer (score 0):

Think you're having trouble understanding how promises work in angular. Promises are asynchronous so you can't just do `$scope.books = BookSearch(data).all();`. You need to wait for the response from `BookSearch(data).all()` and then set the `$scope.books` in a success callback function. Hopefully this [article](http://andyshora.com/promises-angularjs-explained-as-cartoon.html) will help you

Change your service to

```
.factory('BookSearch', function ($http) {
  return {
    all: function(data) {
      var api = "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=" + data;
      // Simple GET request example :
      return $http.get(api).
          success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            // This is the callback function when the $http.get completes successfully so you can remove it
            return data;
          }).
          error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log(status);
          });
    }
  }  
});
```

and your controller to:

```
.controller('DashCtrl', function($scope, BookSearch) {
  $scope.search = function(data) {
    BookSearch(data).all().then(function(data) {
        // This is the callback function when BookSearch(data).all completes successfully
        $scope.books = data;
    }
  };
})
```

Comment: Thank you.  I have managed to figure it out thanks to your help. Is it advisable though to make the call in the all() function? I've in the meantime placed another function called get() in that service which relies on the feedback from the http call to display an individual book. So when if that single book page gets refreshed there's no data available.